# FME assign specific node id with OSM writer

Tags: openstreetmap, fme-form

Is there a way to reassign the node's id value to something I generate?

I did try exposing the `uid` attribute in the write transformer however only produced a new attribute and did not affect the `id` value.

//The question has been changed. To clarify the question at hand, How can I/Can I assign a node's id with a specific value when fme starts to write an osm file?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? Please add some more information, this question is too vague.

Comment: I think I should have asked this question instead.

How can I/Can I assign the node's id value with a specific value?

Answer (score 2):

A negative ID in an OSM file is normally a placeholder for a new object that needs to be created. Editors working against the OSM API will give each new object a unique negative ID, which allows it to be referred to by other objects, and then when they upload the data and the server allocates the real permanent ID they will replace the negative value with the one returned by the server.

How this relates to what FME is doing I don't know, especially as your example doesn't seem to have latitude of longitude information, but it is what negative IDs normally mean.

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is interesting. Does the new id bare any relation to the original negative id e.g (id*-1) or its a more global id from the server?

Comment: None at all, because an editor client has no way of knowing what ID the server might assign when it does the upload.